# In Rails Factory Girl is creating duplicate records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

When I run `rspec`, sometimes all tests pass. But occasionally it give failures. It say `Validation failed: Nyaaid has already been taken`. It looks like Factory girl is creating duplicate entries occasionally.

Here's my Factory Girl code :

```
factory :awardunit do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    nyaaid { "NYAA/N/WP#{ [1,1,1,1].map!{|x| (3..9).to_a.sample}.join }" }
    address "Example Address"
    district "Colombo"
    contact ["23232223"]
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
    insthead "Example Person"
    instheadcontact ["232324223"]
    datestarted "2013-08-04"
    allowedmem 8
    remarks "No"
    disabled false
end
```

Here's my tests :

```
    ### Award Unit List

    describe "pagination" do

      before(:all) do 
        30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:awardunit) }
        visit awardunits_path
      end
      after(:all)  { Awardunit.delete_all }

      it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

      it "should list each awardunit" do
        Awardunit.paginate(page: 1).each do |awardunit|
          expect(page).to have_selector( 'a', awardunit.name)
        end
      end

    end


    ### Award Unit Edit page

    describe "awardunit edit page" do
        let(:awardunit) { FactoryGirl.create(:awardunit) }

        before do 
            visit edit_awardunit_path(awardunit)
        end

        it { should have_title("Edit #{awardunit.name} | SLNYAA Core") }

    end

    ### Award Unit Show page


    describe "awardunit show page" do
        let(:awardunit) { FactoryGirl.create(:awardunit) }

        before do 
            visit awardunit_path(awardunit)
        end

        it { should have_title("#{awardunit.name} Award Unit | SLNYAA Core") }

    end
```

Comment: why not do sequence on the nyaaid as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the restriction that each number must fall between 3 - 9 isn't a true restriction, then you can achieve a truly unique value each time by doing sequence:

```
factory :awardunit do
  ...
  sequence(:nyaaid) { |n| "NYAA/N/WP#{ "%04d"%n } }
  ...
end
```

**Update:**

The following code will do what you want and only generate numbers between 3-9 for each character while providing a unique value **every** time.

```
factory :awardunit do
  ...
  sequence(:nyaaid) { |n| "NYAA/N/WP#{ n.to_s(7).split('').map{|c| "#{c.to_i + 3}" }.join } }
  ...
end
```

*Side Note: If you're looking for some variance in your "fake" data, there is a great gem called Faker that will allow you have 'real looking' fake data.  https://github.com/stympy/faker*

Comment: Thanks it worked. I used 3-9 to avoid duplication because I created a unit earlier in that spec file

Answer (score 0):

Sure it does. You generate `nyaaid` with this `[1,1,1,1].map!{|x| (3..9).to_a.sample}.join` what has only about 2400 possible values. I think the chance to generate a duplicate is quite high.

I do not know how strict validations on that attribute are, perhaps you can just generate `nyaaid` with something like `SecureRandom.hex` or `sequence(:nyaaid)  { |n| "NYAAID#{n}" }`. That would allow more variations. Or you need to generate a valid `nyaaid` with something like this:

```
def generate_nyaaid
  loop
    nyaaid = [1,1,1,1].map!{|x| (3..9).to_a.sample}.join
    return nyaaid if Awardunit.where(nyaaid: nyaaid).count < 1
  end
end
```